# Determine the sum of the series

Tags: calculus

Determine the sum of the series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nn}{(2n)!} x^{2n}$$

I realize that there is a sum by comparison for $\cos x$ which is defined by

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n} = \cos x$$

However, how would I go about converting it to this form as the answer I get does not conform with the posted solution

Comment: What happens when you differentiate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $$\cos x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$$ and differentiate with respect to $x$ to get

$$\begin{align*}
-\sin x&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n(2n)}{(2n)!}x^{2n-1}\\
&=2\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^nn}{(2n)!}x^{2n-1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now multiply by $x$ and make any necessary adjustments in the range of indices.